# How to FQL query in python?

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-fql

Assuming that the user is already authenticated using the javascript SDK, how would you execute FQL queries in python ->

```
 query = 'SELECT page_id FROM page_admin WHERE uid = ' + user_id
```

I've read the documentation and it seems that you got to hit this url ->

https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=QUERY

How do you do this? Also do you need to pass the access token in the url, if yes then how ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=QUERY
Replace QUERY with FQL,
for example：https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=SELECT%20aid,%20owner,%20name,%20object_id%20FROM%20album%20WHERE%20aid=%2220531316728_324257%22

Comment: Hey, how do I convert my query string to that ?

Comment: just add this string before your query :https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=

Comment: You can use `urllib.quote` to accomplish that.

Comment: as in how go I get the %20 signs in between my string ?

Comment: You should use token in some objects expect page,album,movie...  when call some methods, you need use token: https://api.facebook.com/method/comments.get?
access_token=..

Comment: So how do I get the access token ?

Comment: str.replace(' ',"%20") , use this function to replace the spaces by ‘%20’

Comment: from here get your own token by access Friends: https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=... in this url http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/     And the users will give your app the permission to fetch the token

Comment: About get others' token, refer to this article: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/

Answer (score 6):

```
import urllib

query = "SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = \"4\""
print(query) 

query = urllib.quote(query)
print(query) 

url = "https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=" + query
data = urllib.urlopen(url).read()
print(data)
```

output:

```
SELECT name FROM user WHERE uid = "4"
SELECT%20name%20FROM%20user%20WHERE%20uid%20%3D%20%224%22
{"data":[{"name":"Mark Zuckerberg"}]}
```

[FQL reference](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/)

Answer (score 1):

You should use [urllib2](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib2.html), check the urlopen method.

You would need access token depending on the query you are doing, for example if you want to retrieve an photo album you would need the access token and user_photos and friend_photos permissions, for retrieving some fan page information you don't need any.

Comment: Thanks a lot maccha, so let me see if I got you right, I don't need the access token once the user has given my app permission to read that data?

Comment: One more thing ( off topic ), what's the difference between urllib and urllib2 ?

Comment: urllib2 is the successor to urllib. You may also want to check out [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/index.html), which is a simpler alternative to urllib/2.

Comment: nop, once you have the permissions you need the access_token so facebook knows you can query that information.

You would be doing an url like this: `https://api.facebook.com/method/fql.query?query=Selectblablabla&access_token=2227470867|2.AQB36LV969iEVT7q.3600.1311667200.0-652163683|E3ci5ONrD0FQ5-ix0lhXIbH62Xw`

There are some cases where you don't need an access token because the information is public

Comment: So how do I get this access token ?